# Why is the col-md-4 column starting from the right and leaving a blank space on next line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns

I am displaying a list of search results. I am using col-md-4 from bootstrap to display 3 results per row - a bit like 3 cards. However when it moves to the next row it starts from the right and then the next item shows up only on the next one left... basically jumping a column.

Following code to be repeated as many time as needed. End goal is to display results like a grid.

```
<div class="outer-listings-container row-space-8">
  <div class="row row-condensed listings-container">
   <!-- PART TO REPEAT -->
    <div class="col-md-4 row-space-1" data-id="36">
                        <div class="result">
                            <div class="panel-image listing-img">
                                <div id="36" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                                        <div class="item active">
                                            <a class="center-block" href="#">
                                                <div class="center-block">
                                                  <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="#">                                                                                         </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>  
                                          <div class="item">                                                    
                                            <a class="" href="#">
                                                <div class="center-block">
                                                    <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="#">
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>      
                                      </div>                                            
                                    <div>
                                        <a class="left carousel-control height-test" id="36" href="#36" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>

                                    <div>
                                        <a class="right carousel-control height-test" id="36" href="#36" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-overlay-bottom-left panel-overlay-label panel-overlay-listing-label">
                                    <div>
                                        <sup class="h6">€</sup>
                                        <span class="h3">456</span>
                                        <sup class="h6">EUR</sup>
                                        <span class="h6">/session of 2 hours</span>
                                    </div>  
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body panel-body-result">
                                <h4>
                                    <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-xs-2">
                                                    <img src="#" class="avatar-sm" alt="Banana">                                                </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-10">
                                                    <a href="#">Banana R</a>
                                                    <br>
                                                    <small>Banana R</small>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>


                                </h4>
                                <span class="stars2"><span style="width: 0px;"></span></span>
                                <span><b class="review_score">0</b> (0 reviews)</span>
                                <p>blabla</p>
                                <p>more blabla  </p>                                                                                                                                        
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- END REPEAT -->
                   </div>
                  </div>
```

Problem can be seen on the following page: https://gokyma.com/search?location=Paris%2C+France&country=FR&city=Paris&state=IDF&stype=5&selected_date=&selected_time=&_token=ZHXfiseRlAgE3fLY0f1ywr7qYzj9eFxGkSZ2SFIS

Comment: A row must have a maximum of 12 cols.... So max 3 x col-md-4... Here you have 5 * 4 cols = 20

Comment: @neophyte & yenne As per bootstrap docs "If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line." So this is not the issue I think.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your jsfiddle code is not really representative of the issue, but I guess one solution could be adding `<div class="row"></div>` for each series of 3 `col-md-4` that you have in each line. So, the snippet would look something like this;

> `<row> <col-md-4> <col-md-4> <col-md-4> </row>`

Remember, a row can't contain more than 12 columns.... that's another thing to take into consideration...

Comment: Thanks. I overlooked that thinking it would automatically go to the next row after 12columns. Umm...so I need to program that every 3results it moves to the next one. But now when screen size is small I will display only one column per row. How should I handle that - won't there be a conflict with the every 3 results new row?

Comment: Well, Grid classes apply to devices with screen widths greater than or equal to the breakpoint sizes, and override grid classes targeted at smaller devices. Therefore, e.g. applying any .col-md-* class to an element will not only affect its styling on medium devices but also on large devices if a .col-lg-* class is not present. So in your case, if you visit your website using smaller screen, you will see each of your columns in one line.

Comment: Check out this link for having a comprehensive idea about Bootstrap's grid system. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Oh ok so this will work regardless of the rows I insert. Thanks! Let me update that and validate your answer !

Comment: For best results, please add your rows inside a container, The container has 2 purposes:

To provide the width constraints on responsive widths. When the responsive sizes change, it’s the container that changes. Rows and columns are all percentage based so they don’t need to change.
To provide padding so the content doesn’t touch the edge of the browser.